# access session data using PHPSESSID value

Tags: php, websocket, session-cookies, phpwebsocket

I am implementing web-socket server in php for my project. When a user will create websocket connection, it will send PHPSESSID cookie in request headers to the webserver page.
I want to fetch session data for every user using their PHPSESSID cookie value.
This server page can not fetch session value by simply using `$_SESSION['name']`

For every incoming socket connection, i fetch PHPSESSID

```
$cookie = handshake($header, $socket_new, $host, $port);
```

here handshake function will return PHPSESSID cookie.

```
session_id($cookie);
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['name'];
```

For every websocket connection i am receiving right cookie but `$username` only for first connection.
This php file is running in background and i have to authenticate users with their cookie but it seems that `session_id($cookie);` is setting only once.
Is there any way to fetch session data for different PHPSESSID values on this single page.

Comment: Have you tried calling `session_write_close()` before moving on to a new id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @grossvogel mention just using `session_write_close()` function just before `session_id()` function enable me to fetch values for different sessions using PHPSESSID cookie.
Now i can use different sessions within single page

Comment: how do you actually get the session value though?